# Saving Wordpress translation in database

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

I have an API that handles text translation from English to other languages. Translations need to be done once and be saved in the WordPress database for future use.
Example: A single post will be translated into 4 languages which means 4 different versions of a single post.
A user can only access a single version depending on the language he/she has selected.

**The current idea**
Create a database table (**translated_table**) where translated posts will be stored.
At this point, I'm stuck on how the posts will be displayed to the user

**Question:**
Is there a better way to save, map posts and retrieve translated posts such that if you access a Post whose id = 7 in English you can switch the language and still read its translated version stored in **translated_table**?

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a table to hold your languages (wp_languages), and a cross table (wp_postsXlanguages) with a foreign key (wp_posts_ID) to record the translation locations.

Example:
[image]

When you want to retrieve a post in a given language you can use the cross table to locate it. Note that ID's 1 and 4 in the cross table are optional and entirely up to you.